# Variable Selection and Model Likelihood

Tags: bayesian, feature-selection, posterior, model-averaging

Can I derive any (Bayesian) statements about the probability of a parameter given the data and the marginal likelihood of models containing this parameter? For instance, consider a regression setup 
$$Y_t=X_t\beta_k + \varepsilon_{t,k}$$
where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$. 
Data $(Y, X)$ is the same for every model, models differ only with respect to the prior for $\beta_k$: $\pi^k(\beta)=\prod_i^N\pi_i(\beta_i)$ where for some elements $\pi^k_i$ is a point mass at $0$ (the parameter is forced to be 0, or, in other words - it is not included in the regression). The prior for the error term is always centered at $0$.
For different models $\mathcal{M}_k$ we can compute posterior model likelihoods $\pi(\mathcal{M}_k|Y,X)$, being identical to the marginal likelihood if we assume flat priors for the model. 
Assume I computed the model likelihoods for all $2^N$ distinct models, leaving me with a set of $2^{N-1}$ models containing parameter $\beta_k$ for every $k=1,\ldots,N$.

Is there some proper way to compute something like
$$p(\beta_i\neq0|D) \propto \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2^N}\pi(\mathcal{M}_i|Y,X)\mathbb{1}_{\pi_i(\beta_i)\neq 0}$$

I apology for the potential abuse of notation I just don't now how whether this idea makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think "probability of a parameter" is the wrong wording, and strictly speaking, you are also not calculating the probability of $\beta \neq 0$. What you are calculating here is the probability that the true model includes (not) the parameter $\beta$.

Assuming you have made sensible choices for your posterior model weights p(M|D), I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to calculate and discuss this probability.